# Convert sql query to Linq or lambda

Tags: sql, linq, lambda

I have a below query in sql server:

```
select * from
A as a where a.UserId in(select b.id from  B as b) and a.Company is null
```

Can anybody help me to write in linq or Lambda expression.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please never just dump SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), *and* show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Contains, it won't generate an IN subquery but an EXIST subquery but it will be very close to your original SQL

```
var q1 = context.B
    .Select(item=>item.Id);

var q2 = context.A
    .Where(a=>q1.Contains(a.UserId))
    .Where(a=>a.Company == null); // Calling where twice for readability, will generate the same SQL as if you had both weres on a single line with AND, no performance overhead for doing so
```

Or if you'd rather write it in one chunk (will generate the same SQL)

```
var q2 = context.A
    .Where(a=>context.B
          .Select(item=>item.Id).Contains(a.UserId))
    .Where(a=>a.Company == null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using join

```
var t = (from a in entites.b.ToList()
         from b in entites.a.where(x=>x.UserId ==a.id && x.Company==null).ToList()
         select b).ToList();
```

Comment: @Timeout it is alos join like this where(x=>x.UserId ==a.id) refer different of join in linq

Comment: @Timeout i think you not read query. table a should not return all data it is only return condition based data

Answer (score 0):

```
var x= (from a in db.Table1 
        join b in dbTable2 on a.UserId equals b.id
        where a.Company == null
        select a).ToList();
```